# Rake error when creating new app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

Following along on the RoR tutorial, when I try to create a new application, I get the following error:

```
(in /Users/"Username"/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rails-0.9.5)
rake aborted!
ERROR: 'rake/rdoctask' is obsolete and no longer supported. Use 'rdoc/task' (available in RDoc 2.4.2+) instead.
/Users/djones/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rails-0.9.5/Rakefile:3:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I tried to look online, but I couldn't find anything that fixed this issue, at least that I could understand. If anyone else could provide some insight, and hopefully explain it like you would to a five year old, I'd be very grateful.

Answer (score 1):

Might be this will solve your issue http://techatclick.com/rakerdoctask-is-obsolete-and-no-longer-supported-use-rdoctask-available-in-rdoc-2-4-2-instead/